# Neo4j: Updating node for multiplte cases

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am designing a query that can handle updating my node for multiple cases. However, I can't seem to achieve one particular case.

Data model:

Platform for individual owners to sell their cars online The user can buy a car and when they do a calendar node is created with a time stamp as a property (i.e. start_ts). If the user decides to sell the car on a later date, another time stamp is added to the calendar node as a property (i.e. end_ts).

Case:

My issue is when a user has sold his car, but then if the user wants to buy back the car he sold, a new node (Calendar) isn't created.

Note: I use MERGE instead of CREATE for the case where I want to just update the user da

Query:

```
UNWIND $userdata AS user
MATCH (u:User {ID:user.ID})
// Updating properties
SET u += user
WITH u, user

// Check if car is already assigned to another user
OPTIONAL MATCH (cr:Car)<-[:ON]-(cal:Calendar)<-[:BOUGHT]-(us:User)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(cal.end_ts) AND NOT us.ID = user.ID AND cr.ID IN $cars
SET cal.end_ts=datetime()
WITH u

// Check if car is removed
OPTIONAL MATCH (cr:Car)<-[:ON]-(cal:Calendar)<-[:BOUGHT]-(u)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(cal.end_ts) AND NOT cr.ID IN $cars 
SET cal.end_ts=datetime()
WITH u

// Attach car to user
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Car)
WHERE c.ID IN $cars
FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END  | MERGE (c)<-[:ON]-(cal:Calendar)<-[:BOUGHT]-(u)
ON CREATE SET cal.start_ts=datetime())
RETURN DISTINCT u AS data
```

I am not sure how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you describe your data model -- in your question? For example, what is `end_ts` for?

Comment: @cybersam - I also explained above  -  Data model:  -  Platform for individual owners to sell their cars online. 
The user can buy a car and when they do I want to update by creating a time stamp (i.e. start_ts). If said user decides to sell the car on a later date, another time stamp is added to indicate this (i.e. end_ts). This is so I can have a history of the cars bought and sold. My issue is when a user decides to buy back the same car that he sold earlier, a new calendar node is not created.